# In magento 2 what is $F in js.phtml file

Tags: magento2, requirejs

Please open file "vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\attribute\js.phtml".

Go to the function updateRequriedOptions(Line Number 258)

```
 function updateRequriedOptions()
{
    if ($F('frontend_input')=='select' && $F('is_required')==1) {
        $('option-count-check').addClassName('required-options-count');
    } else {
        $('option-count-check').removeClassName('required-options-count');
    }
}
```

Please, what is $F here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to prototype documentation

```
$F(element)
```

Returns the value of a form control. This is a convenience alias of **Form.Element.getValue**

[Check Documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-F/)